# How many times would I have to recursively apply the function ceil(1/3 x) for it to be >= x

Tags: functions, recursion

Suppose I have a function f(x)=ceiling(x/3) where x is a positive integer >1, how many times would I have to apply the function recursively before the result becomes 1?  Is there a non-brute force way to calculate this?

Comment: Won't you eventually end up cycling at $1$?

Comment: It seems like it will always be less than x except when x=1.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut you are right, I edited the question to add a base case that says to stop at 1.

Comment: What I'm saying is that unless $x=1$, you will never become greater than the original $x$. There is a nice way to tell when the process reaches $1$ though, if you would like that.

Comment: Yes, sorry I would like to know when the process reaches 1, that is what I am trying to ask, sorry it's been a while since I've done math like this

Comment: @user439407 That's ok. Do you have any ideas as to where to start? Do you have a guess as to the answer? (Generally a good way to solve problems like this is to try to figure out what the answer is first before proving anything, and the best way to guess that is via trying a few examples). Also, it helps if you put in your question where this problem came up; that way, we can better help you answer it with an answer that will be useful to your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$x = 3n+k$
where
$1 \le k \le 3$,
then
$f(x)
=\lceil n+k/3 \rceil
=n+1
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
x-f(x)
&=3n+k -(n+1)\\
&=2n+k-1\\
&=2(x-k)/3+k-1\\
&=2x/3-2k/3+k-1\\
&=2x/3+k/3-1\\
&\ge 2x/3-2/3\\
&= 2(x-1)/3\\
\end{array}
$

This is at least
$x/2$
when
$2(x-1)/3
\ge x/2
$
or
$x/6
\ge 2/3
$
or
$x \ge 4$.

Therefore,
for $x \ge 4$,
$f(x) \le x/2$,
so that the number of iterations
to reach 4
is $O(\log x)$.

Once there,
$f(4) 
= \lceil 4/3 \rceil
=2$,
$f(3) 
= \lceil 3/3 \rceil
=1$,
$f(2) 
= \lceil 2/3 \rceil
=1$,
and
$f(1) 
= \lceil 1/3 \rceil
=1$.

This is at most
two iterations more,
which does not affect the
$O(\log x)$
result.

For a lower bound,
$f(x)
\ge x/3$,
so at least $\log_3 x$
steps are needed.

Therefore
$\Theta(\log x)$
steps are needed.

Comment: Isn't it exactly $\lceil \log_3(x)\rceil$? (Your answer's not wrong, but I think it's a bit imprecise)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show  that if $3^k < n \le 3^{k+1}$, then $3^{k-1} < f(n) \le 3^k$.